Power of 2 Program in java giving true if i pass number as 2147483647 why?
I have tried writing a java program to find a number is power of two the one which i mentioned  below.
I am passing number as 2147483647 and the output of my program is returning true instead of false.
Can anyone explain what concept I am missing here and how to correct it.
Program
class Solution {
    public boolean isPowerOfTwo(int n) {
        int num = 0;
        int p = 0;
        while(num <= n){
            num = (int) Math.pow(2,p);
            p++;
            if(num == n){
            return true;
        }
        }
        
        return false;    

    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        enter code here
        boolean val = isPowerOfTwo(2147483647);
    
        }


Notes: 1) the mathematical solution, since Math is allowed, would be log(n)/log(2) % 1 == 0 - no loop needed (but be aware that double is not infinitively accurate); 2) the Java solution Integer.bitCount(n) == 1 - no loop, no double; 3) posted code: instead of using pow, it could start with a variable (num)  being 1 and multiplying it by 2 on each iteration to find all powers of 2

@user85421 if you do not want to rely on the presence (and active use) of a popcnt instruction, you’d use Integer.lowestOneBit(n) == n instead. This doesn’t require a dedicated CPU instruction, as the fallback implementation is as simple as (n & -n) == n (which is what we needed to use before Java 5)…

@Holger I am not really interested in determining if a number is a power of two or not, that comment would be better addressed to the OP (just suggested some alternatives for it)

Was just an addendum. SO would have notified you anyway whether I used @user or not…

If a double is greater than Integer.MAX_VALUE, then casting it to an int will give you Integer.MAX_VALUE.
The number you give is Integer.MAX_VALUE, so of course it's going to  be equal to sufficiently large values of (int) Math.pow(2, p).
You will need a different approach, such as actually doubling an int value instead of just calling Math.pow, or some more sophisticated approach.  (The usual ultra-optimized solution is x >= 0 && (x & (x - 1)) == 0, but you probably won't understand that or why it works yet.)
